# Run Symfony without dotenv?

Tags: symfony, nginx, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm deploying my first app with symfony.
I store the enviroment var inside nginx config, like this:

```
fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
fastcgi_param APP_SECRET my_secret;
fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "my url;
```

And i have an .env.dist (with default values) file in the project root directory.

Now my question is: do i really need to install symfony/dotenv package in production? And do i really need the .env file?

It's 2 day that i try different configurations but every time i get this error if i don't install dotenv in prod

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv" not found in /srv/nginx/my_project_name/htdocs/public/index.php:12
```

Or this error if i don't have an .env file

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "/srv/nginx/my_project_name/htdocs/.env" environment file. in /srv/nginx/my_project_name/htdocs/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:557
```

Another strange thing is that if i modify the .env.dist file with "APP_ENV=dev" but the nginx config remains "fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;" the app stop working.

**EDIT**
I moved symfony/dotenv package under the "require-dev" section in composer.json

As per @Mcsy suggestion i commented this line in public/index.php

```
// (new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

The nginx config is this:

```
    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        fastcgi_param APP_DEBUG 0;
        fastcgi_param APP_SECRET your_secret;
        fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "your_db_url_and_psw";
        
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    internal;}
```

All work as intended, I just needed to manually create the directories var/log and var/cache/prod because of the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to write in the "cache" directory (/srv/nginx/my_project/htdocs/var/cache/prod)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You definitely don't need to use the DotEnv package, that's just what Symfony uses by default and is pretty easy to use. ***Why don't you want to use DotEnv by the way***?

You'll see the loading of dotenv the beginning if you open the `public/index.php` file.
This parses the `.env` file, and injects the variable inside `$_ENV`.

```
(new Dotenv())->bootEnv(dirname(__DIR__).'/.env');
```

So you can remove this line.

I don't recommend mixing nginx variables with .env variables, because it's a bad practice to configure your application in multiple places and it will lead you to errors.

Then check that nginx inject your variable inside `$_ENV` variable with `var_dump($_ENV);` at the beginning of the `index.php`.

I recommend you to use the DotEnv package expect if you have a really good reason not to use it.

Comment: nono i don't want to mix nginx and .env. i use .env only for local in my pc. I have a repo on git where i push changes and then i pull to my prod server where i have the nginx config.
I'm trying now your suggestion, i will let you know if it work.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much.the only limitation is that i need to create the var/cache/prod and var/log manualy.
Before i had "umask(0002); // This will let the permissions be 0775" in index.php and the permissions was ok.